# Why is my custom QGIS repository not working in recent qgis-dev version?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I have a custom QGIS repository that worked well with my own plugins.xml on a private server. Yesterday I downloaded and installed the newest QGIS-DEV that now include some changes in the Python plugins manager and I can't make my custom plugins repository work on that version... I can create the repository that effectively see my plugins.xml file but the plugins defined inside that .xml files are not shown in the available plugins list as usual...

Is this new plugin manager version completed? Does it implement custom repository or is it a work in progress?

Thanks a lot

Etienne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new plugin manager is ready for QGIS 2.0, requiring some changes in all plugins.

The qgis-dev mailing list has some advice what you have to change:

http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2013-June/026610.html

http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2013-June/026645.html

https://gist.github.com/NathanW2/5734767

http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/quantum-gis/Python_plugin_API_changes_from_18_to_20

If you have to stick to your plugins, either use QGIS 1.8.0 or a previous nightly build. For Windows OS, they are saved here: http://qgis.org/downloads/weekly/

Comment: I believe the most important changes concerning this question are the change from ____init____.py to metadata.txt and the introduction of the metadata parameters qgisMinimumVersion and the optional qgisMaximumVersion.

Comment: There is not much to be changed, but is has to be done ;-)

Comment: As the question concerns the repository and not the API I wanted to point out the changes which led to the particular problem mentioned in the question ;-)